# Пропал доступ к проектам SVN

Tags: svn

VisualSVN Server Manager
VisualSVN Ltd.
Версия: 2.5.1

У всех программистов пропал доступ к исходному коду в программе SVN.
Для доступа используются доменные учетные записи. Сейчас вместо названий учетной записи отображается набор из букв и цифр. Например, S1-1-5-21-61.. 
Как можно решить проблему?

Answer (score 1):

Набор из букв и цифр называется [SID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Identifier) и является идентификатором учётной записи (пользователь, группа, домен, компьютер).

Я предполагаю, что вы видите SID'ы вместо имён учётных записей в административной консоли VisualSVN Server Manager при управлении настройками авторизации. Такое поведение указывает на проблемы соединения серверной тачки с контроллером домена. Советую сделать следующее:

1. Глядим в [лог VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00028/) и ищем ошибки.
2. На серверной тачке запускаем `dcdiag.exe /s:ИМЯДОМЕНА /v` и смотрим результат,